# How to redirect directory to non-directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all links from www.gambitchessacademy.com/blog/url to www.gambitchessacademy.com/url

For example I want www.gambitchessacademy.com/blog/some-thing to redirect to www.gambitchessacademy.com/some-thing

How can I do this with htaccess? I'm using Joomla and the pages can be accessed by both /blog and non-blog. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Put this rule as **first rule** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog(/.*|)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```